# How to avoid that Music app plays ringtones when playing all titles?

Tags: macos, music

Since Apple has decided to replace iTunes by the Music app, I'm having problems with my ringtones. In iTunes, it was possible to select the type "Ringtone" for these, but now there is only one type "Music" (under *Info > Options > Media type* dropdown).

Because of this, whenever I play all titles, the Music app also plays the ringtones, which is something I definitely don't want to have.

The Music app is obviously not intended to manage ringtones as iTunes did, but what is the replacement for this then?

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to remove the ringtones from Music so they are not played in future.

This then begs the question of how then are ringtones managed between computer and iOS device? For macOS they are added via the Finder directly to the phone, and for Windows it seems iTunes is still the method.

The best writeup I've found is this Howto Geek article which covers the changes since iTunes changed to Music in Catalina.  https://www.howtogeek.com/469085/how-to-add-custom-ringtones-to-an-iphone-from-macos-catalina/

Briefly, the duration is edited, the format exported to AAC, the extension changed to .m4r, and then the file is copied into the iOS device.

I've tested this with Music 1.3 on Ventura 13.0 and transferring the file to iOS 16.1. Works fine.

The split of the various media types that iTunes used to support is most evident with ringtones, Audiobooks and Podcasts. Whereas the latter two are significant enough to warrant their own management apps, ringtones are (though minor) obviously a source of revenue enough to make Apple leave the default management method to iTunes Store purchases for the casual user.